# context:property-placeholder not working if we use property file under src/test

Tags: spring, maven, testing, properties-file

I'm using the property file to configure the datasource in spring :

```
<bean id="mydataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClass" value="${database.driver}" />
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${database.url}" />
        <property name="user" value="${database.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />
         <property name="initialPoolSize" value="${database.initialpoolsize}" 
            />
         <property name="minPoolSize" value="${database.minpoolsize}" /> 
         <property name="maxPoolSize" value="${database.maxpoolsize}" /> 

    </bean>
```

Here is the configuration of this file in spring

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:database.properties" />
```

This property file is under src/test/config/ folder , when I run the test it gives me this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'database.driver' in string value "${database.driver}"
```

Could someone help me on that?

Comment: move it to `src/main/resources/`, that is what gets added to classpath, if this is just for test purpose then move it to `src/test/resources/`

Comment: yes I have moved it to src/test/resources and it's working but for that project I must follow this practise (based on other projects) so I don't know if I must add some configuration on maven?

Answer (score 0):

resources placed in `src/main/resources` would be available to runtime classpath, as they get copied over to target/classes by resource plugin, if you want the properties file specific to test classes then it should be placed under `src/test/resources`

If you want to place it under `src/test/config`

```
<project>
 ...
 <build>
   ...
   <resources>
     <resource>
       <directory>src/test/config</directory>
     </resource>
   </resources>
   ...
 </build>
 ...
</project>
```

Comment: And if I want to put this property file under src/test/config is that possible?

Comment: I have added that config on pom.xml with this config in spring : 
 <context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:database.properties" />but it didn't work